# Two routers with same SSID and MIMO. Will this cause problems?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two routers with same SSID one for upstairs and one for downstairs. The setup works well with all the phones and older laptops. However now I got new Acer V 13 which advertise MIMO. and it's dropping connection all the time unless I rename AP's with different names.

Will MIMO attempt to connect to both SSID's at the same time screwing up connection? How MIMO determines which devices to connect at same time?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Even if they have the same SSID they will broadcast different MAC addresses, so I don't think it's an issue with distinguishing the two. It's more likely that the Acer's roaming sensitivity/aggressiveness is set too high.

When a computer sees multiple access points broadcasting the same SSID, it will connect to the one with stronger signal. If later the signal from another access point becomes stronger, it will automatically disconnect from the original access point and connect to the stronger one. This is called "roaming". It's convenient, but there is usually about a 2-3 second loss of connectivity when the switch happens. If your roaming sensitivity is set too high, your computer may respond to minor fluctuations in signal strength and switch to a different access point much more often than necessary.

Not all wireless adapters allow you to adjust the sensitivity, but try the procedure below:

> 1. Open your network and sharing center
> 2. Click change adapter settings
> 3. Right click the connection with the wireless adapter and select properties
> 4. Under the section that lists the name of the router it will say configure. Click configure.
> 5. Click the Advanced tab
> 6. Click Roaming Sensitivity and adjust it until you re-establish connection (I disabled my Roaming Sensitivity)

[Source](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/connected-with-full-strength-but-unidentified-network-and-no-internet-access-653766.html)